# Enabling --watch in LESS (Less CSS) makes Vim display read-only warning in the current .less file

Tags: vim, less

Everytime I enable --watch: `lessc style.less --watch`

Vim displays the following message every time I try to save something in the `style.less` file:

```
E505 "...style.less is read-only" (add ! to override)
```

So everytime I want to save the file I have to type **:w!**

Any suggestions to eliminate the read-only?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce this.

All I can say is, try on vim :

```
:set noreadonly
```

or

```
:set noro
```

If nothing works, have a look on the file's right.
It may have nothing to do with less.

Comment: sorry it didn't work. I just created the file. And it happen the same with other newly created files.

Comment: I figured out that it only happens when I activate watch mode quit vim and enter again. BUt if I reactivate watch mode the file stop being read-only.